# Lista de asistencia Array con Jquery, JSON y PHP

Tags: php, jquery

Estoy haciendo una función de lista  de asistencia que cree un arreglo desde una tabla para almacenarlo en una base de datos como cadena.

La tabla contiene mucha información, en fin, toda la información la puedo recuperar con este código de JS

```
$(document).on('click','#save',function()
{
  $("table#tbl_asistencia tr").each(function()
  {
      var i = 0;
      var asistencia_arr = [];
      var tableData = $(this).find('td');
      if (tableData.length > 0)
      {
          tableData.each(function()
          {
            asistencia_arr.push($(this).text());
          });
      }
      $.ajax({
        url:'php/control_administrativo/guarda_asistencia.php',
        method:'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        data:{asistencia_arr:asistencia_arr}
      });
  });
});
```

En la consola de google aparece esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Osea que si esta mandando el arreglo.
Del lado de PHP tengo esto

```
<?php
if (isset($_RESQUEST["asistencia_arr"])){$asistencia_arr = $_REQUEST["asistencia_arr"];}else{$asistencia_arr = "";}
$arr = json_decode($asistencia_arr);
print_r($arr);
?>
```

Pero no me está apareciendo nada, no tengo response en la consola de Chrome, al parecer estoy haciendo algo mal en PHP y hasta en JS.
Estoy viendo que aparece como:

```
asistencia_arr[]: UN USUARIO
asistencia_arr[]: A
asistencia_arr[]: A
```

Me preocupa que no tenga un índice el arreglo y no poder acceder a él.
Por ejemplo

```
asistencia_arr[0]: UN USUARIO
asistencia_arr[1]: A
asistencia_arr[2]: A
```

¿Cómo puedo resolverlo y obtener los valores en PHP?
Gracias a todos.

Comment: Podrías pasar el "console.log()" que estás haciendo? Probá poniendo console.log(asistencia_arr[0]); y vas a ver que funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta corta es **NO TIENES QUE RESOLVERLO** los índices de los Arrays están implícitos:

```
echo asistencia_arr[0] //debe mostrar "UN USUARIO"
```

En una respuesta un poco más larga, para ser consistente lo que junta y envía JQuery contra lo que obtiene e interpreta PHP normalmente usaríamos un array asociativo pero JavaScript no funciona de esa manera, usamos un *Object Literal* en su lugar:

```
var person = {opcion1:"John", opcion2:"Doe", opcion3:50, opcion4:"blue"};
```

Por último estás haciendo un `POST` así que en PHP los datos también están en la variable `$_POST`y lo que tienes es un Array en la variable `asistencia_arr` algo similar a esto:

```
$_POST['asistencia_arr'] = ["UN USUARIO", "A", "A"];
```

Que como dijimos al principio, tiene índices implícitos, tenemos lo siguiente:

```
echo $_POST['asistencia_arr'][0]; //"UN USUARIO"
echo $_POST['asistencia_arr'][1]; //"A"
echo $_POST['asistencia_arr'][2]; //"A"
```

Por último, específicamente en tu código tienes un `json_decode()` pero en la pantalla que muestras me parece los datos NO están viajando como JSON; *esto puede ser lo que está rompiendo todo.*

Antes de cualquier cosa, en PHP imprime lo que le está llegando para saber si en efecto estás recibiendo un JSON ya que la opción `dataType` en tu función ajax es para decirle a JQuery que tipo de respuesta esperar:

```
<?php
 print_r($_REQUEST);
 print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: Gracias, tenías razón no hizo falta convertir nada.